# MVC4 : Cannot insert the value NULL into column ,but it's not a null value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, null

Hope everyone are ok , i trying to to insert a new record to database by "LINQ" and there is a problem  !!

Model :

```
[Table("Rate")]
public class Item_rate
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Up { get; set; }      
    public int Down { get; set; }

    public Item_rate(int t, int u, int d)
    {
        Id = t;
        Up = u;
        Down = d;
    }
    public Item_rate(int t) { Id = t; }
    public Item_rate() { Id = 1; }
}

public class RRDBContext : DbContext
{       
    public DbSet<Item_rate> itrat { get; set; }
}
```

Database :

> Table =Rate
>    Pk= Id  -->int
>        UP  -->int
>        Down -->int

//none of those allow nulls

Controller:

```
Item_rate f = new Item_rate(y);

f.Id = y;    
f.Down = 0;    
f.Up = 0;

ratdb.itrat.Add(f);

ratdb.SaveChanges(); //HERE IS THE EXCEPTION
```

IN Web.config :

```
 add name="RRDBContext " connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Recommender.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

The Exception :

> {"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'C:\USERS\ADMIN\DESKTOP\RECOMMENDER.MDF.dbo.Rate'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Comment: Is your `Id` field set up as an identity?

Comment: Post the SQL column definition for `Id`. It needs to be auto-increment (IDENTITY in ms-sql). And then all your `f.Id = y;` statements need to go.

Comment: thanks to all of you i set up the Id to identity and it work :)